# Average of a date column in sql

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a column of datatype `DATE`. I wish to calculate the average of this column.

The column contains the same date but still I want to perform average on this column. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you imagine the average of a date column would be?

Comment: Define what the average of `2016-Feb-01`, `2015-Sep-23` and `2012-Jan-31` is .....

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE;
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE;
DECLARE @DaysRange INT;
DECLARE @MidDate DATE;
DECLARE @AverageDate DATE;

SELECT TOP 1 @MinDate = [Date] FROM DateTable ORDER BY [Date] ASC;
SELECT TOP 1 @MaxDate = [Date] FROM DateTable ORDER BY [Date] DESC;

SET @DaysRange = DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate);
SET @MidDate = DATEADD(DAY, @DaysRange / 2, @MinDate)

SELECT TOP 1 @AverageDate = [Date] FROM [DateTable] WHERE [Date] < @MidDate ORDER BY [Date] DESC

SELECT 
    @MinDate AS [MINDATE],
    @MaxDate AS [MAXDATE],
    @DaysRange AS [DAYS IN RANGE],
    @MidDate AS [MIDDATE],
    @AverageDate AS [AVERAGE DATE (WHAT YOU LOOKING FOR)]
```

I used this "algorithm":

Get numer of days between minumum and maximum date in column (this is our `@DaysRange`). Then devide this number by 2 and add to min date (`@MidDate`) - this is real average date in column. If you are looking for an average date from column records, then `@AverageDate` is your value.